# Will Spring enviroment.getProperty() access file every time or it will remember?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-environment

I have a Spring MVC application. I am using `someprops.property` file to get some global properties.

I am using Spring's Environment to get this.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

In some method

```
env.getProperty('some.prop');
```

My Question here is, will it read the file every time the program calls env.getProperty() or it will remember the last accessed prop and return from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. By default properties are read once but you can make them reloadable.

See [here](http://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/)